# Greasemonkey to save specific data on the web page, to a database, has access errors?

Tags: json, jquery, greasemonkey, cross-domain-policy

I'm trying to extend the usability of a photo-gallery site using Greasemonkey.
The site has a thumbnail for each photo gallery and when you click those thumbnails, they open their own gallery pages.

The problem is that the website updates its galleries very often and I forget the last gallery which I've viewed (new galleries moves the old ones to the next pages).  I want the web site to remember the galleries which I've visited and show them in different border color.

It's very easy to change their styles on a click event, using jQuery, but want to save the visited gallery IDs to my local database, in order to read them and change their styles when I loaded the page next time.

Here is my post code:

```
$(".user_gallery").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $("p", this).attr("style", "background-color:yellow"); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "http://localhost:58364/SaveData.aspx/SaveUserGallery",
            data: "{'galleryID': '" + $("p", this).text() + "'}",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("true!");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error calling the web service.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But of course this gives me cross domain errors:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load .... Origin ... is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My server-side code is simply a `.net` web method which runs on my local server and saves galleryIDs to my SQL server db. I'm a member of that photo gallery site and it runs on a different domain.

I'm not an expert web or JS programmer, so I don't know how to solve this problem. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to handle this.  The easiest for you, since you control your own server is to set the [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers on your local server.  See ["I want to add CORS support to my server"](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).

But, if you don't want to do this, or in cases where you don't control the server, Greasemonkey handles cross-domain AJAX with [the `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` function](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest).

Change the script like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

$(".user_gallery").each ( function () {
    $(this).click ( function () {
        $("p", this).attr ("style", "background-color:yellow");

        GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
            method:     "POST",
            url:        "http://localhost:58364/SaveData.aspx/SaveUserGallery",
            data:       "{'galleryID': '" + $("p", this).text () + "'}",
            headers:    {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            onload:     function (response) {
                            alert ("true!");
                        },
            onerror:    function () {
                            alert ("Error calling the web service.");
                        }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Although I don't recommend creating a bazillion different anonymous functions, inside an `.each()`, like that. (That's a subject for a different question.)